# Why do people write G-d instead of God in writing and on digitial media?

Tags: halacha, names, shemos-sacred-names

I see many people here (and not just here) writing G-d.
Aren't G-d's names sacred only in Hebrew, and even in Hebrew isn't it ok to write the names digitally (and have it displayed on a screen) and it's forbidden only in writing?
Are there any Halachot in this matter?

Thanks.

Comment: A.) Force of habit from what we're used to writing on-paper, or reading in-print. B.) If anyone were to print the page onto paper, it would cause less problems. But agreed, if it stays digital, it would be allowed.

Comment: There are people who use the number 0 instead of the letter o for digital display in order to avoid some of the hyphenation problems that some output programs (such as Windoze) can present.